# Wildcard search for array<string> in Athena

Tags: sql, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table in Athena where one of the columns is of type array.
I tried the below query to get output containing **earth** but doesn't work.
How do I perform a wildcard search in this column?

[image: Example array column:]

Expected output after wildcard search:

[image]

```
select * from mytable
where contains(myarr,'eart%');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from memory, so it might need a bit of tweaking, but you can use a filter on the array elements

```
where cardinality(filter(myarr, q -> q like 'eart%')) > 0
```

filter creates an array of matches and cardinality tests for one or more elements in the array

Comment: This works very well Thank you very much, Are there any other methods available just for curiosity?

Comment: you can use `unnest`, but I think it's a bit ugly- I spent a lot of time coming up with this, because it also works in PrestoDB, which was one of my requirements